# Optimal way to store "stack" or sequence of objects in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, optimization, azure-blob-storage, storage

I am looking to create mobile software that displays a "stack" of objects to a user; these "stacks" can be comprised of either videos, or text, that users can navigate via clicking up or down (similar to tiktok but allowing for text support as well). Each "stack" would correspond to some unique ID, and the user can select "stacks" to view.
I would like to store and retrieve the object/text files that comprise a stack in AWS S3. What would be an optimal way to store videos and text such that it allows for easiest and most efficient retrieval?
In this case, optimal can mean either most organized or most resource efficient, tips on both are welcome and would be very helpful.
Solutions integrating other AWS technologies are also welcome (i.e storing ID's in DDB and retrieving based on that, etc.)

I tried simply storing all files in S3 with a folder corresponding to each ID, and it worked but navigating within individual folders was difficult. I also trie d

Answer (score 0):

The core element for you application would be a database that retains details of each 'stack'.

For each **stack** you would store information like:

- Stack ID
- Owner ID (user)
- Permissions (eg public/private, who can view/edit)

For each **item** in the stack, the database would store:

- Item ID
- Stack ID (linking to the above)
- Item type (text, video, image)
- Content:

  - For **text** items, store the text/html
  - For **images and videos**, store a URL pointing to the content in S3

You'd probably also have a table for storing **usage metrics** so you can determine which stacks and items are popular:

- Stack ID
- Item ID
- Timestamp
- User ID

The key thing to notice is that the **database** is the most important element for your application. The fact that images and videos are stored in S3 is a very minor point.

Your main focus should be on how to **store** the data (like shown above) and how to **retrieve** the data. For example, a web app should be able to call an API and request a Stack. The response would be a JSON version of the stack and its items. This API could also be used by a mobile app.

When the app goes to display a video or image, it would use the URL stored in the Item to refer to Amazon S3. This way, the end-user's app would access S3 directly rather than having to retrieve the data via the app. You can use [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) to provide time-limited access to private objects in Amazon S3.

While you might think that a **mobile app** just needs an app on the phone that calls S3, you'll probably discover that it **also needs a backend** to handle authentication, user management, management of the 'stacks' and 'items'. For example, if somebody reverse-engineered your mobile app and got your S3 credentials, they could access S3 directly and store/retrieve/delete objects. Much better to have an authenticated API to a back-end that manages the storage and 'stack' contents.

**Bottom line:** Storage is simple. Instead, concentrate on the **architecture of your application** and focus on the APIs between the front-end and the back-end.

Comment: First, thank you for the detailed and well thought-out response! I had a follow up question about 2 potential designs 
1) Having a database as you described it, with each stack being a link for certain items and then retrieving said items from S3 via pre-signed urls
2) Having a database with the stack id's, with each id simply linking to an S3 bucket containing all items in that stack and iterating over every item in the bucket.
Would the second approach be much less efficient/optimal? One of the issues I see with using something like DDB is that it is much less mutable than an S3 bucket.

Comment: It's your app, so it's your choice! However, listing the contents of an S3 bucket is **very slow**. Each API call can only retrieve a maximum of 1000 objects. If each stack is in a separate directory and you only request the listing of that directory, then it should be fine. However, if your app doesn't know whether each item is text or video until actually reading content from S3, then the app will perform poorly since it needs to retrieve data from S3 before even knowing how to display the item. Thus, you would want the database to contain information about each item in a stack.